# Which data type to use in java?

Tags: java

I am actually , looking whether exist any structure or interface in java

```
1 -> A
1 -> B

2 -> A
2 -> B
2 -> C
```

which store the details as

```
 1 -> {A,B}  and 2 -> {A,B,C}
```

Like , if I use map , it might be return as

```
 1 -> B and 2 -> C
```

I am looking for something that can return as

```
 1 -> {A,B}  and 2 -> {A,B,C}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you could try and use a map of arrays...?

Comment: You could create a `Map<Integer, Character[]>` or a `Map<Integer, List<Character>>` or use String instead of Character, depending on your real use case.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information about the properties of the data to answer the question.  For example, are the things you've used `1` and `2` as examples for actually going to be consecutive integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like map of Arrays? You can use map to store any kind of value, you can use map of lists for example:

```
Map <Integer, List<YourObject> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<YourObject>;
```

it should work just fine in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a multi-map. In Java, a multi-map is easily implemented on top of a regular map, by using a collection as the value type.

Alternatively, you could use a pre-cooked multi-map implementation, say [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) from Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (an map whose keys are integers and values are lists of strings)